# Maths without irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory

Has anyone imagined so far a consistent mathematical system which can do without irrational numbers? I am writing a philosophy disertation where I claim that mathematics cannot even be imagined without irrational numbers, that irrationality is a consequence of any "sound" mathematical system.

Comment: What do you mean by "can do without"?  Algebraically speaking, we could always just work in the rationals and choose not to define irrational numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?

Comment: Not only that, there are mathematical systems that don't have numbers at all.

Comment: Irrationals come from filling in the "gaps" in fractions. If you want to use numbers to measure, the theorem of Pythagoras will *force* you to accept irrationals or at least algebraic numbers (till you get to circles and $\pi$). If you are only interested in algebra, then there are other ways of filling in the gaps.

Comment: Computers, for example, have no idea about irrationals and this doesn't stop us from using computers to approximate irrationals, well at least those computable (e.g. non computable one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant)

Comment: It's kind of hard to imagine how long the diagonal of the unit square would be in such a universe. Philosophically, I think you'd be on shaky ground.

Comment: The length of the diagonal of a unit square in the real world comes with lots of philosophical issues attached, but the irrationality is a rather unconvincing one when you cannot even measure a length precisely in theory.

Comment: @Mihai You might read Stillwell's *Mathematics and its History*. One of his recurring themes is the tension between arithmetic (where irrational numbers are complex and difficult) and geometry (where they arise naturally and unavoidably.)

Comment: Phenomenalism of course, to borrow a philosophical term. Except that now $\mathbb{Q}$ is the "stimuli".

Comment: @MJD: OP is asking about "a consistent mathematical system", not about the universe.

Comment: The whole point of the real numbers is that our number system *is* based only on rational numbers. Irrational numbers are defined in terms of rationals. If we didn't care about exclusively using rationals, we would have just axiomatized irrationals or treated them intuitively, but we don't do that because human beings find rational easier to understand than irrationals.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It seems to me that in a system with numbers and operations, theres a point when the result of operating it is irrational - for example in arithmetics, the solution to some simple equations or infinite series will be irrational. But this is because of the way the numbers and operations are defined in the framework of arithmetics. My intuition is that even in other kinds of mathematical-logical systems which can be imagined, at some point irrational measures will appear. I would like to understand if this is something which has been proven true or false so far. Thanks!

Comment: @Mihai A big problem in your latest comment is your use of the term "mathematical-logical systems". What on earth does that mean? And what does "irrational numbers will appear" mean?

Comment: Jack, I mean a formal system. Irrational will appear meaning that using the operations as they were defined by whoever created this formal system, the result of some operations will be an irrational number - i.e with a measure forever undetermined to full precision

Comment: @MJD thank you, I will get he book

Answer (score 1):

The standard construction of irrational numbers is as sequences of rational numbers that, as Cauchy put it, "converge on themselves". Here's one such sequence
$$
      \{ 1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414, 1.4142, 1.41421, 1.414213, ... \}
$$
The differences between all numbers in the tail of the sequence, past a certain point, are small. When you square such a sequence, the resulting sequence is another of the same type (sequence converges on itself) which converges to 2. In other words, decimal expansions are really just rational numbers which try to converge to something; Mathematicians finally figured out in the last part of the 19th century that one could just define the sequence to be the limit! Very strange idea, but it works. One identifies as being the same all sequences that converge on themselves and whose difference sequences converge to 0. A single real number becomes the class of all such equivalent sequences.

Comment: TAE, thanks this is a very good perspective of what are these numbers (infinitely converging on themselves, therefore in fact everything is irrational and only at limit can some numbers be rational). The question is however slightly different: can there exist a theoretical, non canonical, but coherent system which does not need this kind of 'irrational infinity'?

Comment: @Mihai: It's a fascinating feat of logic that allowed such a definition. If you take any power of such sequences, then you get other such sequences. The absolute value of such a sequence is another such sequence. So you can extended the definitions of polynomials and other basic functions to include these new "numbers." It's hard to imagine, but Mathematicians could not rigorously make sense of real numbers until the last part of the 19th century; so you know there's some deep thought that went into this. What this basically means, though, is that you could stick with rational approximations.